# How to restore joomla article html pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, joomla

My website has installed wordpress automatically over my joomla site about 3 times now.  Previously I managed to fix it and I don't remember how, this time I went into cpanel and uninstalled wordpress directly, leaving only joomla installed.

Well apparently in this process of wordpress coming and going, a bit of my joomla stuff was deleted from the file directories, particularly the website root.  I lost my index.php and all the article html pages.

If I log in to website.com/administrator I can see all the articles still. I know they are there and I can still edit and save them, yet the article alias no longer exists.

I can still go to the direct article link, and the page is there, but the menu options I have set up are all pointing to their own respective article alias, and these no longer function because they show up like `website.com/alias.html` and that doesn't have anything.

I was hoping I could just open the article and save it and it would automatically recreate these alias pages.  I was successful in recreating the root index.php by downloading a separate joomla locally and just reuploading the index.php file via ftp...  However unsuccessful in all the other root directory files that are missing.

I am using `Joomla! 3.9.11 Stable [ Amani ] 13-August-2019 15:00 GMT` and I haven't been able to find anything that is actually related to this issue.  Every time I type anything related into google it's something to do with people having issues inserting custom html into their articles.

I don't really want to reinstall joomla to avoid screwing more things up.  I don't mind reinstalling the template if that is what it takes, mostly because I am assuming that won't interfere with all the articles I have already built out...  Majority of which are custom HTML that I would prefer not to rewrite and waste precious time on... I am using `jd_newjersey` template as it's labeled in my joomla interface.

Sorry for not having any real code and mostly just a wall of text but to sum up the issue:

I lost my article alias html pages and I need a way to get them reproduced as simply as possible so I can restore the basic functionality of my website. Note this is not the pages like `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5` but rather just `website.com/alias.html` that joomla creates automatically...

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two main files that prevent WordPress and Joomla sharing the same folder are `index.php` (as you have already found) and `.htaccess` if it exists.

In the root folder of your website e.g. `/public_html` or similar, copying `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` will enable the Joomla .htaccess file and this will hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Okay great.  I moved it from the local version of joomla that I had, into the `/public_html` directory.  With `.htaccess` updated I get this message on the article pages: `Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: There may be a directive in the `.htaccess` file that is not compatible with the hosting environment. Commenting out lines by trial and error might be one way to solve this although you'll need the line with "RewriteEngine On" to keep url rewriting enabled.

Comment: Okay, I commented out every single line, no good.  I commented out every single line one by one.  That was no good either.  At this point, my website has been down for a couple days I think I am just going to try to reinstall joomla.

Comment: Okay, I was going through and backing up all my files.  Then something dawned on me...  In my particular website through godaddy, there is a public_html directory, and then a website directory.  So out of like 6 websites or something like that, there is `public_html/website1`, `public_html/website2`, ect...  I went into the website directory rather than `public_html` and updated the .htaccess there.  Reloaded my test page, and it worked.  I haven't tested vigorously to make sure it's still functioning but I'm assuming it is.  Thank you for the help sorry I missed that.